# Resolving - cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$') datatable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables

I get an error every time I want to initialize a table in React using Datatables.
I searched for solutions but could not find any.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import dt from 'datatables.net-dt'
$.fn.DataTable = dt

$('#tableId').DataTable()
```

Worked for me, thank you!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32317305)

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this problem in React, follow these steps;

- Install [All dependencies](https://datatables.net/manual/installation) and the [Jquery](https://jquery.com/download/) plugin  If it fails without it

```sh
npm install datatables.net    # Core library
npm install datatables.net-dt # Styling
npm install jquery
```

- Import and setup Datatable configurations

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import dt from 'datatables.net-dt'
$.fn.DataTable = dt
```

And in your render body, just write the following line of code to resolve the issue

```
$('#tableId').DataTable()
```

> Let me know if this helps :-)
> `<HappyCoding/>`

Comment: what's happening here? you're self-answering your own question, and you close it with "Let me know if this helps :-)" ?

Comment: @GrafiCode, yes. I have been trying to find a solution to the problem and after doing so, I thought of sharing having not seen the answer on StackOverflow.

The reason why I added Let me know if it helps is - Encase the solution does not work for someone, they're free to comment and share how they solved it.